# How to keep an object alive while going between a class and views in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, object, swiftui, view

I have a class named `AudioRecorder` and a view named `RecorderView`. `Audiorecorder` has the following functions

- startRecording() --> Starts recording and gets recording start time.
- stopRecording() --> Stops recording and gets recording stop time.
- saveToCoreData() --> Saves startTime, stopTime and rating to coredata

How it works is, `RecorderView` lets the user to start and stop a recording by calling the functions in `AudioRecorder`. Once the user stops the recording, a new view named `RatingView` is shown. User provides a rating in `RatingView` and hits submit. By selecting submit, `saveToCoreData` in `RecorderView` is called with the user provided rating. The problem here is that, by the time the view calls `saveToCoreData`, `startTime` and `stopTime` are lost. This is why they are "nil" and only `rating` has a proper value. How do I keep `startTime` and `stopTime` alive for the next use? Is there a way to fix this problem?

```
import SwiftUI

struct RecorderView: View {
    @ObservedObject var audioRecorder: AudioRecorder
    @State private var showRatingView = false
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            if audioRecorder.recording == false {
                Button(action: {self.audioRecorder.startRecording()}) {
                    Image(systemName: "circle.fill")
                }
            } else {
                Button(action: {self.audioRecorder.stopRecording(); showRatingView = true}) {
                    Image(systemName: "stop.fill")
                }
            }
            VStack {
                if showRatingView == true {
                    NavigationLink(destination: SurveyRatingView(rating: 1, audioRecorder: AudioRecorder()), isActive: self.$showRatingView) { EmptyView()}
                }
            }
        }
    }
}



struct RatingView: View {
    
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) var moc
    @State var rating: Int16
    @ObservedObject var audioRecorder: AudioRecorder
    
    @State private var displayNewView: Bool = false
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            
            Text("How was the recording experience?")
//          RatingView(rating: $survey)
            Button(action: {
                self.audioRecorder.saveToCoreData(rating: rating)
            }) {
                Text("Submit Response")
            }
        }
        .navigationBarBackButtonHidden(true)
    }
}
```

This is what the class `AudioRecorder` looks like

```
class AudioRecorder:  NSObject, ObservableObject {
    @Published var startTime: Date
    @Published var stopTime: Date
    
    func startRecording() -> Date {
        self.startTime = Date()
        //Start recording related code here
    }
    
    func stopRecording() -> Date{
        // Stop recording related code here
        self.stopTime = Date()
    }
    
    
    func saveToCoreData(rating: Int16){
        let aRec = AudioRec(context: moc)
        aRec.uuid = UUID()
        aRec.startTime = self.startTime //This is nil
        aRec.stopTime = self.stopTime  //This is nil
        aRec.rating = rating  //Only this has a proper value
        
        try moc.save()
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you put some code to clarify your question?

Comment: Watch Demystify SwiftUI

Comment: Did you keep a strong reference to your `AudioRecorder`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your "showRatingView" `VStack` you are passing a new instance of `AudioRecorder`.  You should pass the instance you already have:

```
VStack {
    if showRatingView == true {
        NavigationLink(destination: SurveyRatingView(rating: 1, audioRecorder: self.audioRecorder), isActive: self.$showRatingView) { EmptyView()}
    }
}
```